# How to know when a specific process is stuck?

Tags: java, process

Is there a way to know when a specific process is "stuck" in Java?

I'm running an external application from my java program. Sometimes, this app hangs. I would like to know when this app stops working so I can kill it from my code. I'm thinking of some type of monitoring from a different thread in my code.

Any toughts?

Comment: do you have a strict definition of what 'hang' means?  how would you tell the difference between it hanging and just being really slow?

Comment: I'll actually don't know exactly. This app is a dev build, so it's common that it hangs. I was thinking in monitoring the status of the process. Something similar to when in windows task manager the status says "Not responding". I'd need it to work in Mac too though.

Comment: Blanco: damn, misread your question... It all depends on how the I/O happens between your external app and your Java program. I launch external apps, but I *always* use temporary files for IPC (because consuming streams are just too messy and lock-prone: and believe me, I've run more external apps on more OSes than most Java programmers :)   I wrap all my external apps in "nohup app ... &" calls, get back the PID and *"kill -9"* (which guarantees, on Un*x, to release *all* the resources of the app) from Java when the Java app ain't getting "normal" output from the external app.

Answer (score 1):

Under java 6 you can get a thread dump for All threads. If you snapshot these every minute you Can see what goes ón.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be to ask what you mean by "stuck".  Is it in an infinite loop?  Is it deadlock?

By the nature of the question I'm guessing you don't know, but if all you want to do is kill it when it hangs, you can have it write some output to a file periodically.  Another process can monitor this file, and if some number of periods go by without seeing output, you can kill it then.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, However, I can't modify the running app because I don't have access to its code.

Comment: Given that you can't modify the application, and without knowing how the application interacts with the rest of the world, or how you know that it has hung, I don't believe this question is answerable.

Comment: Thanks for your answers danben. I was thinking there might be a way of  to know the status of the process in the OS from Java

Comment: You could monitor the CPU activity of the app, and if the CPU is close to zero for a prolonged period, kill it (assuming that when it hangs, CPU drops)

Comment: @Carlos Blanco: on Un*x, you could at least detect some status programmatically, like the "zombie" one...

Comment: Can the downmodder please explain?

Answer (score 0):

If the other app is also java, you could use the Java Service Wrapper for monitoring and restarting it in the event that it is hung.

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp